# minimize the number of postbacks

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i have senerio like that

i have three table

department

```
    [Dep_No_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Dep_Name] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Dep_Code] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
```

test

```
[Test_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Test_Code] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[Test_Name] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[Tests_DepartMent_Code] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Tests_Group_Code] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Tests_Rate] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
```

and

sub_test

```
  [Sub_Test_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Sub_Test_Code] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Sub_Test_Name] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Sub_Tests_Test_Code] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Sub_Tests_DepartMent_Code] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Sub_Tests_Group_Code] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Sub_Test_Rate] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
```

In my aspx page I show the Departments in a DropDownList when the user select the Department a request is going to server side and the Grid is bind with the Tests. And in this Gridview i have a Checkboxes in all rows when user check this check box a request is again going to the Server Side and second Gridview is bind with Subtests according to Tests,in all that ,Postback is occur is many times which decrease my efficiency because user select multiple test and Subtest from multiple department. Can any one give me idea,how i simlify this senerio by which minimum number of Postback occur

(in test and subtest grid i have 5-5 columns)

Comment: you can try using Ajax `UpdatePanel` for this purpose your server will be limited.

Comment: Could you please format your question so that it supports case sensitivity?! I'm not a machine.

Comment: So sorry Tim,I format my question ,i think now u r able to understand this.

Comment: I don't think the UpdatePanel is a good option. I would have not used an Update panel unless it's a very small page, and not much concerned of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need  quality and a well performing result, as well as if you can spend a little more time, jQuery with a good grid plug-in is the best option.
here's a good option.
[jqGrid demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

UpdatePannel is a pretty bad option, which should be only considered when you have a limited time,  not much concerned in performance, and when the page with less content.

Comment: will jqgrid run on the server side as gridview

Comment: It'll not be similar to GridView (but they have a similar code-behind oriented version which is commercial) so there will be a slight learning curve which is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make Jquery AJAX calls to get the conditional data or can use AJAX Update Panel instead.